# Finding a root word

Tags: string-manipulation, text, dictionary

```
w = "successfully";
{DictionaryWordQ[#], WordDefinition[#], PartOfSpeech[#], 
   WordData[#]} &@w
```

> ```
> {True, {"with success; in a successful manner"}, {Entity[
>    "GrammaticalUnit", "Adverb"]}, {{"successfully", "Adverb"}}}
> ```
>
> [image]

---

After some search, I discovered `WordStem`; so I tried.

```
WordStem /@ {"successfully", "successfull", "successful", "successor",
   "successive"}
```

> `{"successfulli", "successful", "success", "successor", "success"}`

Note that the first element in the answer list is wrong and fails `DictionaryWordQ`, while the second input had a wrong spelling. "successor" was not reduced further; albeit there was some success.

Briefly tried the following, hoping it would trigger some cascade:

```
FixedPointList[WordStem, "successfully"]

{"successfully", "successfulli", "successfulli"}
```

---

**Question**

Though there is a built-in function `WordStem` to find the root word, what would be a dependable solution for such a problem? Is a workaround/upgrade to this functionality available?

Thanks for your replies and solutions in advance.

Comment: just a hint, you could try `Through`. ```w = "successfully";Through[{DictionaryWordQ, WordDefinition, PartOfSpeech, WordData}[w]]```

Comment: From the documentation `WordStem uses the Porter stemming algorithm.`. A Porter stem is not necessarily a dictionary word, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thanks for the link. Now I know what a stem is not. I am guessing that I will have to make/find a suitable lookup table and use it instead.